# Initialize counter variable in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to use a variable inside a Common Lisp function as a counter, started from a desired number and used inside a loop while.

```
(defun x(c)
   (setq i 4)
   (loop while condition do 
        ;do something
        (incf i)))
```

the instructions `setq` and `incf` are not appropiate for this. What is the standard way to manage a counter variable in clisp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) is explained in details in [§22. LOOP for Black Belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html).

```
(defun x (c)
  (loop 
    for i from 4 
    while <condition> 
    do <something>))
```

Answer (score 7):

In Common Lisp you need to define your variables. Your variable `i` is undefined. That's a mistake.

```
(defun x (c)
   (setq i 4)                 ; undefined variable i
   (loop while condition do 
        ;do something
        (incf i)))            ; undefined variable i
```

Define your variable:

```
CL-USER 9 > (defun x (c)
              (let ((i 4))     ; defining/binding local variable i
                (loop while (< i 10) do
                      (print i)
                      (incf i))))
X

CL-USER 10 > (x :foobar)

4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
NIL
```

But as the other answer by *coredump* shows, `loop` provides its own way to define a variable and iterate over it.